# select max 10 values in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have website of application  which sells applications online.on the home page  i want to  display top 10 products based on number of times they have downloaded.i tried to fetch product ids from sql server database 2008.but the query size increases when i go from high download count value to lower value.because i fetch one product id in one query.so total 10 queries for top 10 applications.

so i want to know whether is there any way to  fetch top 10 applications easily.

i have table named product.It has two fields product_id,purchase_count.i want to get 10 product id who has highest download_count values.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. When questions are frequently down voted it is usually an indication they are being perceived as a "plea for free code". This is *not* that kind of site. You will get a much better response (and less down votes) if you post your code along with a brief explanation of how the results differ from what you need. Do not worry if the code does not work. Posting it helps us demonstrates you have put some effort into solving the problem yourself and are not just asking others to write code for you. It also helps us to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select top 10 * from your_table order by douwnload_count DESC;
```

EDIT:
Since you only need product_id use:

```
select top 10 product_id from your_table order by download_count DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you have the column "download_count" stored? In another table?

In that case you would have to do an inner join to that table, and order by the download_count column. If it is in the same table you can do something like this :

```
select top 10 product_id,purchase_count from product.It order by purchase_count DESC;
```

If in another table it would be :

```
select top 10 product_id,sum(download_count) as downloads 
from product.It as p
      inner join download.it as d on d.product_id= p.product_id
group by product_id
order by d.download_count DESC;
```